# Se uma variável int não receber nada do select ela é zero ou não

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Digamos que eu tenha esse bloco:

```
declare @teste int
declare teste_cur cursor
for
select campo1 from tabela
.....
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @teste = 0
  select @teste = campo1 from tabela where campo2 = condicao2
end
.....
```

Se o select não retornar nada, a variável @teste continua com zero(0) ou não?

Vendo as respostas dos colegas abaixo, resolvi fazendo esse IF

```
if @rx_num_novo is null or @rx_num_novo = ''
    begin
        --Aquifaço meu Update/Insert/Delete
    end
```

Comment: Não, não ficará.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, mas como eu faço um if com ele então? pego somente se ele for maior que zero no count? O que vem então? Null?

Comment: @pnet olha a minha resposta... Você tem dois selects, um sem condição e outro com. Se houver ao menos um registro em sua tabela, o valor da variável será o valor do resultado do select mais interno, caso contrário ficará nulo.

Comment: Para fins de testes: para saber se o SELECT retornou linha (e teve valor @teste assinalado), utilize @@rowcount

Comment: O select da minha resposta tal como feito na pergunta a variavel volta nula e meu teste funciona tal como esta na resposta. O select feito pelo @Renan não volta nulo, volta vazio, mas não nulo, e por isso que no caso dele a variável não se altera.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, eu sei, tive que marcar apenas uma. Se o sistema permitir arcar duas, marco a sua também.

Comment: Nem estava me referindo a isso. Aliás, nem tinha notado nisso. Me referia a diferença existente entre os dois casos.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, não foi intenção minha também nada, apenas responder. A sua resposta está corretíssima, testei e funcionou. Veja que eu testei nulo e vazio para atender meu requisito, não que estivesse errada. Coloquei Null e Empty(Vazio) por conveniência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui, e se a instrução SELECT que preenche uma variável não retornar nenhuma linha, a variável não tem seu valor alterado.

i.e.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso, o laço do fetch só será executado se houver ao menos um registro no select mais externo. Dessa forma:

- Se houver registros retornados pelo select mais externo, mas a condição do select interno não for atendida no último registro obtido pelo fetch (`campo2 = condicao2`), a variável @teste terá valor zero;
- Se houver registros retornados pelo select mais externo e a condição do select interno for atendida no último registro obtido no fetch (`campo2 = condicao2`), a variável @teste terá o valor do campo `campo1`;
- Se o select mais externo não retornar registros, a variável terá o valor padrão do inteiro no SQL Server, que é nulo.

Comment: Renan e Reginaldo, eu testei o IF com null e 0 e nada aconteceu. No resultado, apareceram em branco o valor da var, essa é a dúvida, pois branco não é null, mas não consigo atribuir a uma var int. Isso é que gerou o post e tenho duas respostas agora. Vou testar melhor e posto o que tá acontecendo. Fiz um outro post, que tem a ver com isso também, mas tive que fazer outro, pois parece ser outra pergunta.

Comment: @pnet se você tentar imprimir o valor de uma variável nula, você vai obter um resultado em branco.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @teste int
set @teste = 0;
select @teste = campo1 from tabela where campo2 = condicao2 -- considerando que volte nulo
if ( @teste is null ) 
  print 'nula'
else
  print 'não nula'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]